# Tail index estimation to prove non-stable fat tail distribution

Tags: fx, statistical-finance

Currently I am analysing the stylized facts for some EURO FX rates. This [paper](http://ww.long-memory.com/returns/Guillaume-etal1997.pdf) states that we can prove the fat tail distribution of the FX log returns via the computation of **the tail index**. For a person who is not familiar with extreme value theory how can I reproduce the results of table 3 in the paper ?